How should I remove ceramic tile on a conventional mortar bed?
I need to remove a bunch of this tile to reveal the wood flooring underneath for some vinyl.
I was just going to start going at it with a hammer and a crowbar, but if anyone has any tips I’d happily hear them!

https://imgur.com/a/1Y7EQSf

What kind of vinyl?  Solid core LVP/LVT can be installed directly over the tile. Otherwise it's grunt work. Hammer and chisels.

Vinyl what?  Sheet/tile might be easier to just glue down some underlayment.  Planks might be too high, but can go on top.

Just like when removing asphalt shingles, sometimes you can get it to come up as a sheet. Try a potato fork or roofing shovel. With a a bit of luck you can pry the mesh loose from the subfloor and take it all out in large (heavy) sections, which you may need to segment with an abrasive saw.
Be sure to use eye protection. That tile glaze is essentially glass, and it will be shattering.

+1 for the shingle stripper. One of my favorite demo tools. I would add a posthole digging bar, which goes for about $30 and worth every penny.

I think you have two choices if DIYing: manual methods, and mechanical methods.
You can use a big demo chisel and a hammer.  The hard way.
You can rent/buy a demo hammer (basically a small electric jackhammer) and a big spade bit.
You need to break up the mortar bed under the expanded metal mesh, then cut (e.g. angle grinder) the mesh into sections small enough to be able to be folded and placed into contractor bags (unless you've rented a dumpster).  Tiles should basically fall off the mesh/mortar, or be easily knocked off.
Might need another scraper bit to clean up the wood, depending how cleanly the mortar comes off.
